# datetime format error in mozilla browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, firefox

I have done the date and time format in angularjs,it is working fine in chrome browser.But it is not working in Mozilla browser.

**Controller.js**

```
 myAppControllers.filter('datetime', function($filter)
  {
    return function(input)
   {
    if(input == null){ return ""; }  
    var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input),
                          'MMM dd yyyy - hh:mm ss a');
    return _date.toUpperCase();
    };
  });
```

In chrome browser the output would like this

```
MAY 20 2016 - 08:15 32 AM
```

But in Mozilla the result is

```
UNDEFINED NAN 0NAN - NAN:NAN NAN PM
```

Comment: it look like something that will work just by doing `<span ng-if="myDate">{{ myDate | date:'MMM dd yyyy - hh:mm ss a'  | uppercase }}</span>`

Comment: What is the value of *input*? I'll bet `new Date(input)` is returning an invalid date because you are attempting to parse a string using the Date constructor when you should never do that.